# Add rainfall image layer to leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, r-raster

I am trying to show the UK's Met Office rainfall images overlaid onto a leaflet map. The Met Office image is available as an image in png format via the Met Office API.  I am a novice with leaflet, raster etc. so am probably doing something obviously wrong. The rainfall image is 500x500 (pixels, I assume) and is bounded at 48N to 61N and 12W to 5E.  I can show the image on a simple plot, as per the following simple code (I have left off the APIkey for confidentiality reasons, so unfortunately this is not reproducible, unless [blank] below is replaced with a valid Met Office Datapoint API key).

```
url5<-"http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/layer/wxfcs/Precipitation_Rate/png?RUN=2018-05-18T03:00:00Z&FORECAST=36&key=[blank]"
rpg<-GET(url5)
r1<-content(rpg)
plot(c(100, 250), c(300, 450), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
rasterImage(r1, 100, 300, 150, 350, interpolate = FALSE) #this works, so this suggests that r1 is recognised as a raster image
```

However, when I try to do in leaflet using the following simple code, I get an error message, as shown below the code.

```
leaflet() %>%
addTiles() %>%
fitBounds(lng1=-12, lat1=48,lng2=5,lat2=61) %>%
addRasterImage(r1)
```

The error message is:

```
Error: inherits(x, "RasterLayer") is not TRUE
```

Anyone know how to solve this please?

Thanks

David.

Comment: Your example does not work. Can you include the appropriate libraries to run the code. After the last line of your first block of code I get `Error in UseMethod("as.raster") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.raster' applied to an object of class "raw"`.

Comment: It is because png are not projected raster.